# Identifying groups in Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I am running a complicated group by statement and I get all my results in their respective groups. But I want to create a custom column with their "group id". Essentially all the items that are grouped together would share an ID.

This is what I get:

```
partID | Description 
-------+---------+--
11000  | "Oven"      
12000  | "Oven"      
13000  | "Stove"     
13020  | "Stove"     
12012  | "Grill"
```

**This is what I want:**

```
partID | Description | GroupID
-------+-------------+----------
11000  | "Oven"      | 1
12000  | "Oven"      | 1
13000  | "Stove"     | 2
13020  | "Stove"     | 2
12012  | "Grill"     | 3
```

"GroupID" does not exist as data in any of the tables, it would be a custom generated column (alias) that would be associated to that group's key,id,index, whatever it would be called.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect.  If you group by description, then you would get three rows rather than five.  Can you fix your question?

Comment: This looks pretty much like a case for using a enum instead of string.Maybe you like to have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: Oracle corporation should really implement Window functions in MySQL Oracle for this.. the custom rank "workarounds" in this topic are pretty expensive even with indexes and wont scale on large datasets..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query that returns the five rows:

```
select partId, Description
from part p;
```

Here is one way (using standard SQL) to get the groups:

```
select partId, Description,
       (select count(distinct Description)
        from part p2
        where p2.Description <= p.Description
       ) as GroupId
from part p;
```

This is using a correlated subquery.  The subquery is finding all the description values less than the current one -- and counting the distinct values.  Note that this gives a different set of values from the ones in the OP.  These will be alphabetically assigned rather than assigned by first encounter in the data.  If that is important, the OP should add that into the question.  Based on the question, the particular ordering did not seem important.

Comment: +1. That's pretty crafty. Can you explain a little better why that works?

Comment: I ran this and it only gave me one Description, It didnt give me all of the descriptions available.

Comment: I updated my original posting to make it more clear.

Comment: @dvaini . . . This query should return one row per row in the `part` table.  If you are only getting one row, I suspect that you have an aggregation function (`min()`, `max()`, etc.) in the outermost `select`.

Comment: I need to re-ask a new question. My query is actually a group by with multiple fields it is grouping by. I didnt want to paste my entire query in here because its a big one and same with the result set.

I am grouping by multiple fields and I will just re-ask.

I also wanted to keep the query simple to see the simple solution, rather than over complicating my question. But I think I have to throw the huge query in here in order for it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get it:

```
SELECT p.partID,p.Description,b.groupID
FROM (
  SELECT Description,@rn := @rn + 1 AS groupID
  FROM (
    SELECT distinct description
    FROM part,(SELECT @rn:= 0) c
    ) a  
  ) b
  INNER JOIN part p ON p.description = b.description;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6e55/8)</kbd>

This gets assigns a diferent groupID to each description, and then joins the original table by that description.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments in response to Gordon's answer, I think what you need is a derived table to generate your groupids, like so:

```
select
t1.description,
@cntr := @cntr + 1 as GroupID
FROM

(select distinct table1.description from table1) t1

cross join
(select @cntr:=0) t2
```

which will give you:

```
DESCRIPTION     GROUPID
Oven             1
Stove            2
Grill            3
```

Then you can use that in your original query, joining on description:

```
select
t1.partid,
t1.description,
t2.GroupID
from

table1 t1
inner join
(
select
t1.description,
@cntr := @cntr + 1 as GroupID
FROM

(select distinct table1.description from table1) t1

cross join
(select @cntr:=0) t2


) t2
on t1.description = t2.description
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf214/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT partID , Description, @s:=@s+1 GroupID 
FROM part, (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
GROUP BY Description
```